# How to stop program code by using EOF

Tags: c, eof

I am done with the input and process part of the program, but I don't know how to terminate the program with EOF. Here is my int main(void) code:

```
int main(void)
{
    int size;

    int n;

    char preorder[26];
    char inorder[26]; 

    while(/* I don't know what to put on this part...*/)
    {
        for(n = 0; n < maxSize; n++)
        {
            preorder[n] = ' ';
            inorder[n] = ' ';
        }
        preIndex = 0;

        scanf("%s %s", preorder, inorder);

        size = strlen(preorder);

        struct node *root = constructTree(inorder, preorder, 0, (size - 1));
        printPostorder(root);
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Every function is working fine, I've checked them separately. Basically the user wants to end this program by pressing Ctrl + Z (I'm working on windows, so it's Z). I have to use EOF. Thx in advance

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1561770/c-programming-eof-as-a-character?rq=1

Comment: Put any true value after the while (e.g. `while(1)`, you want to explicitly `break` if he user hits Ctrl-Z.

Comment: Worth noting perhaps that at the console in Windows EOF is sent with Ctrl+Z but in Linux it is Ctrl+D.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the return value of your input functions. `scanf` will return the number of items stored or EOF if it encounters end-of-file.

As Anthon says, you can use `while(1)` as your loop control, and use `break;` to exit the loop.

```
while(1) {
    if (scanf(...) == EOF)
        break;
}
```

Don't be tempted to use the function called `feof()` because it only checks a flag in the FILE structure, ie. it will only detect an EOF *after* you've tried to read it. It can be used in a multi-tiered error handling structure, though.

```
while(1) {
    if (scanf(...) < N_elements_specified) {
        if (feof(...)) {
            /* EOF detected */
            break;
        } else {
            /* some other cause of insufficient data */
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what do you usually put in the ... for (scanf(...) == EOF)?

Comment: That depends entirely on the specific program. `scanf` will return EOF or not for any valid arguments.

Answer (score 3):

You want to do something like:

```
while (scanf(...) != EOF) {

}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can add `cin` and take input from `preorder` while `preorder` has characters left:

```
while (cin >> preorder)
{
    ...
}
```